# Is this data being sent securely?

Tags: objective-c, ios, security

I just want to see if sending login information through the HTTPBody is secure like this? or should I encode the username and password?

```
NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", _userName.text, _passWord.text];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://website.com/ilogin.php"]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString *reply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", reply);
    if (reply == @"Login Successful") {
        _loginResponse = [NSString stringWithString:@"Successfully Logged In"];
    } else if (reply == @"Incorrect Password") {
        _loginResponse = [NSString stringWithString:@"Incorrect Username or Password"];
    } else if (reply == @"LOGIN_ERROR_USERNAME") {
        _loginResponse = [NSString stringWithString:@"Incorrect Username or Password"];
    } else {
        _loginResponse = [NSString stringWithString:reply];
    }
```

Comment: This is as unsecure as it could possibly be. You should use HTTPS (SSL encrypted HTTP communication) instead for a start. Also sending the password in plaintext is something you might want to prevent. Instead send a hashed version of the password and compare it on the server with a hashed version. Actually, don't even store plaintext passwords on the server but only hashed versions of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not secure. The only way to be truly secure is to use HTTPS, but that requires you to pay for a certificate as iOS won't connect to unverified HTTPS services.

You can improve the security by using a one-way hash on the username and password. Basically append the username, password and a so-called "salt" value, which should be a random sequence that you generate once and then hard-code into your app.

Once you have that string, apply a hash such as MD5 or SHA1 to the string to get a nonsense sequence that you send as the authentication.

On the server side, you then loop through the users and apply the same algorithm to each username and password, using the same salt value, then see if the result matches what was sent, which tells you who the user is, but doesn't let anybody listening in know who it is.

To be even more secure, apply that hash when the user first registers and store the hash value instead of their password in your database, that way, if your website is ever compromised, you won't have to tell all your users that they need to change their passwords (like a few high profile sites have had to recently).

It's also more efficient to store the hash in the database for lookup purposes anyway, so you don't have to loop through all the records and apply that hash to each one every time somebody logs in.

Comment: thank you, I'm using a phpbb3 forum board, I'm not exactly sure how it stores the passwords and everything, but I'm going to look into that and look into how to do all the suggestions you made, thank you for you help

--Edit--

I just found out that phpBB3 uses a salted hashes when storing all passwords

Comment: You don't necessarily need to pay for a certificate: you can use a self-signed certificate and ensure that the subject identifiers match.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that iOS refuses to connect to self-signed SSL servers, but I'll admit it's not my area of expertise.

Comment: For future readers of this post: iOS does support self-signed SSL certificates. Check out the documentation for NSURLConnectionDelegate to see how it's done.

Comment: NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender is more appropriate.